# Why do we need global-forwards and global-exceptions in struts?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts

I have a basic question in struts why do we need to have `<global-forwards>`and `<global-exceptions>` in struts-config.xml. If we can achieve the same things with `<action-mappings>` itself.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

### `<global-forwards>`

Consider you are validating the username password for different urls like

- `update.do`
- `insert.do`
- `delete.do`

If it is a valid user, you need to proceed the necessary action. If not, you need to forward to the login page. Without a *global forward*, you must add  a `login` form mapping form to **every** action:

```
<action-mappings>        
   <action path="/insert" type="controller.Insert">
      <forward name="success"  path="/insert.jsp"/>
      <forward name="failure"  path="/login.jsp"/>
   </action>     

   <action path="/update" type="controller.Update">
      <forward name="success"  path="/update.jsp"/>
      <forward name="failure"  path="/login.jsp"/>
    </action>

    <action path="/delete" type="controller.Delete">
       <forward name="success"  path="/delete.jsp"/>
       <forward name="failure"  path="/login.jsp"/>
    </action>        
</action-mappings>
```

Instead of repeating the `<forward name="failure"  path="/login.jsp"/>` you can declare this in `<global-forwards>` like below

```
 <global-forwards>
   <forward name="failure"  path="/login.jsp"/>
</global-forwards>
```

Now you can remove the `<forward name="failure"  path="/login.jsp"/>` in the action mappings.

---

### `<global-exceptions>`

When you receive `java.Io` exception, instead of handling manually for each you can declare globally as below.

```
<global-exceptions>
   <exception type="java.io.IOException" path="/pages/error.jsp"/>
</global-exceptions>
```

I hope this clarifies your problem.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, let say if there is HTTP 500 error page and need to forward back to login page, <action-mappings><action path="/loginAction" .... </action><forward name="login_form".... /></action-mappings>, how this can be done, thanks

Comment: I have to disagree with user1900662 - this is the perfect length, imo. It answered my question exactly (and was the first result in google so I imagine i'm not the only one...)

Answer (score 4):

If you are talking about Struts 1, `global-exceptions` are `ExceptionHandlers` that deals with some `Exception` for all the actions, so you don't have to declare it per action and avoid duplication.

`Global-forwards` have the same idea. If you have forwards with the same path in different actions, you can avoid duplication by declaring just one `global-forward` and all the actions can use it. With `global-forwards` you can also avoid hard-coded URLs in your jsps, eg, you could declare a global-forward like `<forward name="loginLink" path="/login" />`
and then in your jsp  `<html:link forward="loginLink">Login</html:link>`.